# Font-Awesome icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, icons

Having a lot of trouble here, it works with an earlier version of font-awesome, but not the newest one.

Imported in HTML via

```
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Modified font-awesome.min.css like so:

```
 @font-face{
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    src:url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.1.0');
    src:url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.1.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0') format('woff'),
    url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.1.0') format('truetype'),
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}
```

Using an icon like so:

```
<i class="icon-anchor"></i>
```

But to no avail... I have the EXACT same code with the older version (diff versions), and it's not working.

Comment: Things that are the same are not different.

Comment: @reisio +1, very constructive comment.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's enough to go on here. Could you post a link to an example of this?

Comment: @BrettD, but there's no +1 on my comment! Seriously though, after a while you realize that many people seem to believe in magic, and somehow don't realize that simple fact, that things that are the same are not different. What could be more important than helping them to unlearn this?

Comment: Can you put your code on JSFiddle? That way we can see exactly what's wrong and perhaps why it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried to put the older version back ? Also, if you would be so kind to give the version numbers from and to which you are upgrading.

Comment: To get help you need to post a link.